# Compare list of data, Create new list depending on Condition, Mathematica

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

I have a bis aount of climate Data. Measuered over two Years on different Stations every ten Minutes. Some Measuremts are Missing (Diffferent on each Station)

I want to pick the rows with the same date and time and put them into a new table to start comparing.

the tableorder is Date, Time, Value, Date2 ,Time2, Val2

```
   {{ 20120806, 600, 253,  20120805, 1350, 565}, 
    { 20120806, 610, 280,  20120805, 1400, 609},
    { 20120806, 620, 306,  20120806, 600, 282}, 
    { 20120806, 630, 333,  20120806, 610, 305}, 
    { 20120806, 640, 353,  20120806, 620, 334}, 
    { 20120806, 650, 380,  20120806, 630, 364}, 
    { 20120806, 700, 406,  20120806, 640, 386}, 
    { 20120806, 710, 426,  20120806, 650, 409}}
```

the Result should be a table with one date,time and the two Values.

thanks

Comment: something like `Select[list, #[[1]] == #[[4]] &][[All, {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}]]` (If that's not what you mean you should show expected output for your example )

Comment: i just tried. it gives me just an empty {} is there a possibilty to ad a second condition?    { 20120806, 620, 306,  20120806, 620, 334}, 
    { 20120806, 630, 333, 20120806, 630, 364}, 
    { 20120806, 640, 353, 20120806, 640, 386}}

and then without the dates
{{ 20120806, 600, 253, 282}, 
    { 20120806, 610, 280, 305 },
    { 20120806, 620, 306, 334}, 
    { 20120806, 630, 333, 364}, 
    { 20120806, 640, 353, 386}}

Comment: and would it be possible to return the missing measurements as a missing flag?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now

```
Select[mix, #[[2]] == #[[6]] && #[[3]] == #[[7]] &][[All, {1, 2, 3, 5,
6, 7, 8}]]
```

Comment: the example data only has 6 columns.. maybe you are missing some commas?

Answer (score 0):

```
list = {{20120806, 600, 253, 20120805, 1350, 565}, {20120806, 610, 
    280, 20120805, 1400, 609}, {20120806, 620, 306, 20120806, 600, 
    282}, {20120806, 630, 333, 20120806, 610, 305}, {20120806, 640, 
    353, 20120806, 620, 334}, {20120806, 650, 380, 20120806, 630, 
    364}, {20120806, 700, 406, 20120806, 640, 386}, {20120806, 710, 
    426, 20120806, 650, 409}};
```

break into separate lists:

```
{alist, blist} = Transpose /@ Partition[Transpose[list], 3];
```

pull out all the date/time values from both lists

```
alldates = 
  Union@Flatten[{list[[All, {1, 2}]], list[[All, {4, 5}]]}, 1];
```

function to add "missing" to a list if the supplied date/time is missing:

```
addmissing[dlist_, list_] := 
  Module[{r}, r = Select[list, #[[1 ;; 2]] == dlist &];
    If[Length@r == 0, Append[dlist, "Missing"], First@r]] 

Flatten[{addmissing[#, alist], addmissing[#, blist]}, 1] & /@ 
  alldates // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. thats great. now i´m trying to get the average of every hour. appreciate your help!

Comment: i´m running the code right now and it´s taking hours. any tips? i have 100000 rows to compute...